# MySQL - Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'database_name.#sql-776_f23d' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE afil2 (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `apellido` varchar(30),
    `nombre` varchar(30),
    documento varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD COLUMN afil2 bigint(20);
ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD FOREIGN KEY(afil2) REFERENCES database_name.afil2(id);
```

In the last line I get the error `Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'database_name.#sql-776_f23d' (errno: 150)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This generally means you have a type mismatch on your foreign keys. Are you using InnoDB?

Comment: do you have another table called ordenes?  Becuase you are creating a table called afil2, then adding a column to afil2 called afil2 and then make it a foreign key to the afil2 column on the afil2 table in reference to id in the afil2 table.  Something doesnt seem right there

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` should tell you why.

Comment: @MrJamin I assumed that the table had been created using InnoDB by default. Thank you!!! If you want, you can post the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Overflow012: Unless configured otherwise, `InnoDB` only became the default storage engine in MySQL v5.5.5; see [InnoDB as the Default MySQL Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-default-se.html).

Comment: @ObieMD5 This is not quite true - if the column is nullable then you can have no corresponding entry in the referenced table.

Comment: @eggyal wouldn't myisam just ignore the foreign key constraint?

Comment: @Jack: Quite probably - I was merely responding to the OP's comment that he had expected the table to be created with InnoDB by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE ordenes ADD FOREIGN KEY(afil2) REFERENCES database_name.afil2(id);
```

I think you're supposed to substitute your actual db name in this line for `database_name`.

Comment: @N.B. If you try this in Mysql 5.5.23 the error you get for leaving a non-existant database_name in the query is as per the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both your table are of the same type (InnoDB, for example). Otherwise the constrains will fail.